# "he wanted to know what love {is/was}"

Tags: word-choice, tense

> Surrounded by memories, he wanted to know what love is.

I think this line is grammatically correct since the guy wanted to know what the definition of love is; but I wonder if **was** should be used here because it happened in the past.

Comment: I think either will work, but just like many questions on this site that ask about a single sentence the answer depends on the context of that sentance. In other words we need to see that sentance within a larger text.

Comment: @AdrianHHH Thanks for replying; I made up this sentence so we don't really have a bigger context here hh, but I just wanted to say, "He wanted to know what true love is," thus I suppose I don't need to use 'was,' but I still asked as I didn't know if my assumption was right or not

Comment: @Angyang As Adrian pointed out, both verbs are acceptable. Which is appropriate depends entirely on the context in which the statement is set. And since there is no context, there is no saying which is better.

Answer (score 1):

> Q. Would you use **is or was** here?

It is not all about grammar *To answer this question first you need to define the sentence*

*"Surrounded by memories, he wanted to know what love is."* grammatically the correctness of this statement has been assessed in comments and I have nothing further to add. However as a sentence the above has no meaning. What is the connection between memories and the meaning of love? Especially as there is no surrounding context. We are not given any context of the link between the phrases used in the sentence. There is no indication of what the memories were about. Football, World War 2, emotional experiences or last nights soap operas? You could just have well written "Surrounded by apples, he wanted to know what love is/was." In mathematics 3x3 has no meaning you would complete the expression 3x3=? So why should we write an incomplete expression when we use words not figures?

*"Surrounded by his happy/sad/bittersweet memories, he wanted to know what love is."* would suggest that life's experiences had made him question the meaning/definition of love. It would also provide the context for selecting **is or was**

Although I would suggest that wanting to know in this case is more likely to be wondered, pondered or remembered what love is/was.

***"Surrounded by his happy/sad/bittersweet memories, he remembered what love was."***